# Python class method fixed argument

Tags: python

I saw a piece of python code here. I want to know why the programmer has defined width=0 and height=0 ? aren't they supposed to be received by the init method ?

```
class Rectangle:
    sides = 4
 
    def __init__(self, width=0, height=0):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
 
    def calculate_area(self):
        return self.width * self.height
 
 
rectangle_1 = Rectangle(5, 10)
rect_area = rectangle_1.calculate_area()
```

Comment: its called a default value

Comment: They're defaulting the value, in an attempt to make the script more "accepting". Unfortunately, if that is the entire script those defaults should not be there. The reason is: They have provided no other way to assign them aside from directly, and no form of reporting if either are 0.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy -- "should not be there' is simply not true.  There's nothing wrong with having the user set `x.width = 7` directly, and there's no need for a warning if the default value is used.  I might want to create a list of dummy entries that I fill in later.

Comment: @TimRoberts ~ that all depends on how much you like hunting down problems. The presented script is wide open and ready for nothing but trouble. I could give you a much better example and all the reasons why it's better, but it would end up being "off-topic".

Comment: If this were a course on software engineering best practices, yes.  But in this context, it is not a useful addition.

Comment: @TimRoberts ~ Of course it's useful. You don't get good at something by doing everything the wrong way, and eventually realizing it. Defend it all you like, defaulting the most fundamental properties of anything to `0`,`None`,etc in it's constructor is terrible practice.

Comment: Thanks @OneMadGypsy . I'm learning Python, so it could be great if you could give me an example of why a default value in a constructor is not suggested. Sharing a link will also work for me.

Answer (score 0):

These are default values. He assigned width and height to 0 by default if he didn't pass arguments in initialization.

So:

rectangle_1 = Rectangle (5, 10) -> means width =5 and height=10

while

rectangle_1 = Rectangle () -> doesn't error instead by the default value
width =0 and height=0.

Comment: Thanks Rashed for your help. I got it

Comment: Any time my friend